# CSV I/O operations using shell?

Tags: shell, csv

I have written a bash script that generates a CSV file. However, I now want to run a loop before I generate this CSV file and deduct certain value from each column.

Here is my code for better understanding:

```
for loop; do
    $VAL /*global*/
    file="./out_base.txt"
    while IFS=' ' read -r f1 f2 f3
    do
            $VAL = $f2
    done <"$file"

    file="./out_lw.txt"
    while IFS=' ' read -r f4 f5 f6
    do
            $((f4-VAL)) >> val_lw.csv
    done <"$file"
done
```

**out_base.txt** is in format: a  b  c

**out_lw.txt** is in format: d  e  f

**Desired output:** val_lw.csv should look like:
b-e /*(where - is a mathematical minus operator)

e.g:
out_base.txt:

sim_ticks 32768 #number of ticks

sim_ticks 31111 #number of ticks

out_lw.txt:

sim_ticks 65433 #number of ticks

sim_ticks 74333 #number of ticks

intented val_lw.csv:

32665

43222

However, I am not able to perform the mathematical operation and get the desired results.

**Corresponding Output**: val_lw.csv is a blank file.

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Please show input and corresponding output as no-one seems to understand at the moment...

Comment: apologies. Updated the post.

Comment: Are there multiple lines in the files because you appear to be looping over multiple lines yet you appear to always try to assign to the same variable (`$VAL`)? You assign to a variable like this `VAL=$f2`, no spaces either side of `=` and no `$` on left side.

Comment: yes. out_base and out_lw has multiple lines however same number of lines. 
I iterate the code in a for loop. in every iteration, VAL should get the corresponding "b" from Out_base.txt, and should deduct it from "e" from out_lw.txt and store result in a val_lw.csv.

Yes there are multiple lines in both the input files. although all the lines in both the files are in same format and are generated by same code.

Comment: Sorry, it's still very unclear. Please show 3 lines of the input file with actual numbers and the corresponding 3 lines of output with actual numbers.

Comment: out_base.txt:
sim_ticks 32768 #number of ticks
sim_ticks 31111 #number of ticks

out_lw.txt
sim_ticks 65433 #number of ticks
sim_ticks 74333 #number of ticks

intented val_lw.csv:
32665
43222

Comment: Also, updated it in the question with proper formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think life would be easier with `awk` like this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{x[FNR]=$2;next} {print x[FNR]-$2}' out_lw.csv out_base.csv > vl_lw.csv
32665
43222
```

**Explanation:**

Run `awk` on both files, `out_lw.csv` and `out_base.csv`. If reading the first file, save the second field in array `x` indexed by the line number `FNR`, then jump to the next line. If reading the second file, print the corresponding saved value from `x` minus the second field on the current line.

---

If you really want to use `bash`, it might look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Load all numbers from "out_base.txt" into array "base[]"
base=( $(cut -d ' ' -f2 out_base.txt ) )

# Iterate through "out_lw.txt"
line=0
while read a b c ; do
   ((diff=b-base[line]))
   echo $diff
   ((line=line+1))
done < out_lw.txt
```

Comment: I should be using out_base.csv instead of out_base.txt os what you are suggesting apart from using awk ?

Comment: No, the filename extension is unimportant - you can use whatever you like. I am suggesting `awk` as it is a simple one-liner whereas you are going to need a minimum of 5-6 lines of `bash` with either some quite advanced redirections to read two files at the same time, or to understand `bash` arrays. The `awk` just seems simpler.